# How can i check that which section that i clicked for TableViewController inside of prepareForSegue function by Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

My tableViewController have 2 sections.
So i need to check that which section that user clicked?

Then i can send correct value for prepareForSegue function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the segue is made directly from the cell, then the sender argument in `prepareForSegue:sender:` will be the cell. You can use the table view method, `indexPathForCell:` to get the indexPath.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
    let section = indexPath.section
    // other code here
}
```